# How to Extract and copy content from one file to another using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a main.c file which content looks like

```
const uint8 array1[] =
{
0x00,0x12 , ....
....,
....,
....,
}

const uint8 array2[] =
{
0x00,0x12 , ....
....,
....,
....,
}

/* Data dictionary */

const arrayInfoType Images[SIZE] =
{
  /* [0] = */
  {
   /* .pDataSource = */
  (uint8*)array1,
   /* .DestAddr = */
  (uint32)   0x00000000,
  /* .DataLength = */
  (uint32)   0x00002cA7
  },
  /* [1] = */
  {
   /* .pDataSource = */
  (uint8*)array2,
   /* .DestAddr = */
  (uint32)   0x00017000,
  /* .DataLength = */
  (uint32)   0x00026342
  },
};
```

I wanted to copy only DataLength values to a header which looks like

```
#ifndef Img_included
#define Img_included

#define NO_OF_ARRAYS 2u
#define Size_Array0        0x000053A7    
#define Size_Array1        0x0002516C
extern  const arrayInfoType Images[SIZE];

#endif
```

how to overwrite SIZE_Array0 value in header with content of Data length of array 0 form C file and same thing for Array 1 using batch script .

I tried using FINDSTR but not getting proper output.
Script what I was trying to use to extract content of C file .

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /N "uint32" "%InFile%"') DO (
CALL :RemovePrecedingWordA "%%A"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%B IN ('ECHO.%%A') DO (
MORE +%%B "%InFile%"> "%TempFile%"
FINDSTR /V "}" "%TempFile%">> "%OutFile%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%C IN ('FINDSTR "}" "%InFile%"') DO (
CALL :RemoveWordB "%%C"
IF EXIST "%TempFile%" DEL "%TempFile%"
GOTO :eof
)
)
)
GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="

FOR /F "tokens=1-7delims=),[ " %%g IN (q72311923.txt) DO (
 rem test for const uint8 name`
 IF /i "%%g%%h"=="constuint8" SET "#%%i=undefined"
 rem test for (uint8*)name,
 IF /i "%%g%%i"=="(uint8*" SET "name=#%%h"
 rem test for (uint32)   value - datalength only
 IF /i "%%g"=="(uint32" IF DEFINED grabdatalength CALL SET "%%name%%=%%h"
 rem test for   /* .DataLength = */
 IF /i "%%g%%h%%i%%j"=="/*.datalength=*/" (SET "grabdatalength=Y") ELSE (SET "grabdatalength=")
)
:: Now substitute within template

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (q72311923t.txt) DO (
 FOR /F "tokens=1-7delims= " %%g IN ("%%b") DO (
  SET "regurgitate=y" 
  IF /i "%%g"=="#define" (
   FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==#" %%q IN ('set #^|sort /r') DO IF DEFINED regurgitate (
    ECHO %%h|FINDSTR /L /i /x /c:"size_%%q" >NUL
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO %%g %%h        %%r&SET "regurgitate="
   )
  )
  IF DEFINED regurgitate echo %%b
 )
)
GOTO :eof
```

Assuming that the secon listing is of a template (`q72311923t.txt`) and the first (`q72311923.txt`)is your `C` file, and noting that the first mentions `array1` and `array2` but the template has `array0` and `array1` and also that I've used `if /i` throughout to make comparisons case-insensitive,

First I've cleared out all variables that start `#`

Next, examine each line of the `c` file and tokenise using `),[` and <kbd>Space</kbd> as the delimiter set, look for lines that contain significant strings.

If the line is `const uint8 name` then set the variable `#name` to `undefined`.

If the line is `(uint8*)name` then record the name in `name`.

If the line is  `(uint32)   value` then assign the value to the variable whose name is in `name`, but only if the previous line was a `.datalength` line.

and finally, check whether the line is a `.datalength` line and set a Boolean flag that can be tested on its runtime value defined/not defined.

Having established the names and values defined in the `c` file, interpret the template file using no delimiter to assign each line to `%%b` then again using
just <kbd>Space</kbd> as a delimiter.

If the first token on the line is not `#define` then don't change the value of the `regurgitate` flag to `echo` the line verbatim.

If it is `#define`, then check whether the second token is exactly `size_#?` where `#?` is one of the `#names` recorded. If it's found then `echo` the replacement value and set 'regurgitate` to *not defined*

Comment: Thanks @Magoo for the suggestion , I tried the approach but I dont see the datalength being copied to the .h file which I actually wanted . I am checking if this can be adopted to the script what I am writing .
I was also thinking of using " findstr /R /N "uint32" main.c " which displays only the uint32 content and then I can store them into variable , later copy the specific array content to the header file. can you suggest if this is better approach ?

Comment: The code is based on your published samples. For me, it produced `#define Size_Array1        0x00002cA7` to replace `#define Size_Array1        0x0002516C` as `size_array0` is not mentioned in the first `c` sample. If you execute a `set #` instruction, you should get a list of the values found. I don't speak `c` so all I'm doing is trying to extract the data as I see it, Are you testing against the data here, or have you used a different set of files? Are the values you are not seeing not mentioned in any `#define` statement in the template file?

Comment: I am not testing against data.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read second file from stdin
< test2.txt (

rem Search for .DataLength data in first file
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   if defined .DataLength (
      rem Search for desired line in second file and replace data
      call :searchSize_Array_and_insert %%a
      set ".DataLength="
   )
   set "%%a=1"
)

rem Copy rest of lines
findstr "^"

)

goto :EOF


:searchSize_Array_and_insert data
set "line="
set /P "line="
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%line%") do (
   set "var=%%b"
   if "!var:~0,-1!" equ "Size_Array" (
      echo %%a %%b        %1
      exit /B
   )
)
echo/%line%
goto :searchSize_Array_and_insert
```

Output:

```
#ifndef Img_included
#define Img_included

#define NO_OF_ARRAYS 2u
#define Size_Array0        0x00002cA7
#define Size_Array1        0x00026342
extern  const arrayInfoType Images[SIZE];

#endif
```